# Facebook Analytics for Apps with PhoneGap / Cordova

Tags: cordova, facebook-graph-api, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm developing an application for iOS and Android. I use Cordova with https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin
I need to view the results with Facebook Analytics for Apps.
In iOS, it works perfectly without special configurations.
But Android does not provide results on Facebook Analytics for Apps when users access or download the application.
Facebook Analytics for Apps indicates activity only the user accessed through the Facebook login screen.
Is there any way to initialize the application so that this step is not mandatory? In iOS, you do not need this.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you sure you're not seeing any App installs for example from Android in https://www.facebook.com/analytics/<app id>? I'm using https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4 and our app is sending data correctly for both platforms